# Why dialogflow bot stop responding in telegram if i create a telegram bot object with node-telegram-bot-api?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I’ve build a dialogflow chatbot with telegram integration and i need to take paths of images sent by the user in telegram chat. As far as i know dialogflow bot doesn’t listen for images, so i use a telegram bot object for polling messages to get the images, but in this way the dialogflow bot stop responding, even after the polling of the telegram bot is stopped. There is some conflict between the two bot. The only way to “resuscitate” the dialogflow bot is to manually restarting the telegram integration in the dialogflow UI.
There is a way to solve conflict between the two bot so the dialogflow bot continues responding after the telegram bot got the image?
Here it is the code i wrote:

```
const TG = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

function takeImagePath() {
    agent.add(`send an image/photo`);   // work
    const token = 'my telegram bot token';
    let telegramBot = new TG(token, {polling: true});
    agent.add(`tg bot created`);  // work

    telegramBot.on('message',  async function (msg) {
        const chatId = msg.chat.id;
        agent.add('bot dialogflow in the listener');   // don't work

        if (msg.photo) {
            let ImgID = msg.photo[msg.photo.length - 1].file_id;
            let imgPath = "";

            if (ImgID) {
                telegramBot.getFile(ImgID).then((fileObject) => {
                    imgPath = fileObject.file_path;
                }).then(() => telegramBot.sendMessage(chatId, 'image taken'))   //work
                  .catch(error => console.log("error: " + error.message));
            }
        }
        else { await telegramBot.sendMessage(chatId, "it's not an image, telegram bot shutting down");   //work
               await telegramBot.stopPolling();
               agent.add("bot dialogflow active");   // don't work
        }
    });

}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Image intent', takeImagePath);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem is that webhook and polling are two mutually exclusive method of getting messages. So whereas dialogflow-telegram bot use webhook, the telegram bot object that i created use polling
`let telegramBot = new TG(token, {polling: true});`
which automatically delete the webhook.
To solve this problem in necessary to set again the webhook after stopping the polling: `await bot.stopPolling(); bot.setWebHook("your webhook url").then(r => console.log("webhook response: "+r)).catch(err => console.log("webhook error: "+err.message));`

You can find here the webhook url which your dialogflow-telegram bot is using:

https://api.telegram.org/botYourTelegramBotToken/getWebhookInfo

Hope it helps someone.